# Can't send parameters to a MySQL Stored Procedure windows form

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, mariadb

I am trying to insert data in mariadb Stored procedure using the class in vb.net, but I keep receiving error that says **Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE ... expected 12. but 0** what does it mean? and how can i solve this error? did i miss something in my code?

***note: there is no problem in the connection of the database***

```
    Try
        Dim arrParameter, arrParamName
        Dim sParamName As String
        Dim sDataValue As String
        Dim sDataTypes As String
        Dim lCtr As Long
        Dim param(lParameter) As MySqlParameter
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = sStoreProcName
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        InsertUpdateData = False
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sStoreProcName, conn)
        arrParameter = Split(sParameterList, "|", , vbTextCompare)
        If Not Trim(sParameterList) = "" Then
            If UBound(arrParameter) >= 0 And IsArray(arrParameter) Then
                For lCtr = 0 To UBound(arrParameter)
                    arrParamName = Split(arrParameter(lCtr), "$", , vbTextCompare)
                    sParamName = arrParamName(0)
                    sDataTypes = arrParamName(1)
                    sDataValue = arrParamName(2)
                    If sDataTypes = "string" Then
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(sParamName, MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200, sDataValue)
                        cmd.Parameters(sParamName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    ElseIf sDataTypes = "integer" Then
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(sParamName, MySqlDbType.Int32, 3, sDataValue)
                        cmd.Parameters(sParamName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    ElseIf sDataTypes = "double" Then
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(sParamName, MySqlDbType.Double, 5, sDataValue)
                        cmd.Parameters(sParamName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    ElseIf sDataTypes = "varchar" Then
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(sParamName, MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200, sDataValue)
                        cmd.Parameters(sParamName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    Else
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(sParamName, MySqlDbType.DateTime, 200, sDataValue)
                        cmd.Parameters(sParamName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    End If
                Next lCtr
            End If
        End If
        MessageBox.Show(cmd.Parameters(sParamName).Value) 'The result is 0
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
        InsertUpdateData = True
        Exit Function
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

/form

```
       sParameterList = "intPlayerAccountId$integer$" & Label_PlayerAccountID.Text &
            "|intStudentId$integer$" & defaultValue &
            "|intSemesterId$integer$" & defaultValue &
            "|intEducation$integer$" & defaultValue &
            "|intPayment$integer$" & defaultValue &
            "|dblAmount$integer$" & dblCreditedAmount &
            "|dblCreditedAmount$integer$" & dblCreditedAmount &
            "|dblAvailableBalance$integer$" & Label_CurrentBalance.Text &
            "|intStatus$integer$" & defaultValue &
            "|intRequestStatus$integer$" & defaultValue &
            "|intProcessedBy$integer$" & 163 &
            "|intParentId$integer$" & Label_Walletid.Text
        bool = objDataInquiry.InsertUpdateData("sp_Enrollment", sParameterList, 12)
```

UPDATE

[image]

I get the same error ***Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE ... expected 12. but 0***

Comment: I'm going to make a wild guess that it means that the number of arguments provided to PROCEDURE is wrong, it was supposed to be 12 but none were given.  Note that your code is parsing some kind of string to get arguments, but we don't see how that string is provided to your routine.

Comment: Okay, I will update my question, please wait

Comment: There's no point setting the `Direction` to `Input` because that's the default. If you were going to set it though, you wouldn't set it in every `If` block because then you're writing the same code over and over. You'd just do it once, after the `End If`.

Comment: Ugh, this is full of old VB6-era patterns from 25 years ago

Comment: I don't see how `cmd.Parameters(sParamName).Value` is relevant at the end of that code. Surely it's `cmd.Parameters.Count` that you're interested in and surely you should be using the debugger to see it, not a message box.

Comment: Instead of using a string to try to pass the parameters, you should use a [MySqlParameterCollection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code uses a more modern coding style, but I need to emphasize *it's not just about aesthetics.* In addition to fixing the problem in the question, this approaches fixes several issues you may not have known about:

1. The original code creates contention around the shared connection, forcing operations to take place sequentially that might otherwise be asynchronous, and making things *slower* for individual queries by interfering with existing connection pooling ability already provided out of the box.
2. The original code would not close the connection if an exception was thrown. If that happens enough, it can lock you out of the database.
3. Type prefixes like "s" and "arr" were invented at Microsoft. They made sense for VB6 era code based on the coding styles, language features, and tooling of the time. With the improved tooling and language concepts available in .Net, Microsoft's own style guidelines now explicitly ask you NOT to use type prefixes.
4. Exception handling should not be done in this method, but rather a level higher, by code that calls into this method.

```
' Do NOT try to re-use the same connection object throughout your app!
Using conn As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd  As New MySqlCommand(StoredProcName, conn)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(ParameterList) Then Return False       ​
    ​Dim QueryParams = ParameterList.Split("|"c)
    ​If QueryParams.Length = 0 Then Return False
​
    ​For Each param As String In QueryParams
        Dim ParamFields = param.Split("$"c)
        Dim ​ParamName As String = ParamFields(0)
        Dim DataType  As String = ParamFields(1)
        Dim DataValue As String = ParamFields(2)

        Select Case DataType
            Case "string", "varchar" 
                ​cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamName, MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = DataValue
            Case "integer"
                ​cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamName, MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = DataValue
        ​    Case "double" 
            ​    cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamName, MySqlDbType.Double, 5).Value = DataValue
        ​    Case Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamName, MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DataValue
        End Select
    ​Next param
    conn.Open()
   ​ cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Return True
End Using
```

Is every VarChar field really 200 characters long? That seems like a *really bad idea*. It's only a matter of time before you need to deal with a longer field. Also, what do you think will happen when you have parameter data which includes a pipe (`|`) or dollar sign (`$`) as part of the text? You should really be sending this data as it's own class type, instead of needing to parse out a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are STILL creating the parameters incorrectly. You had it wrong before and you've changed it to something else wrong. The overload of `Add` that you're using is for when you're calling `Update` on a data adapter to save changes from a `DataTable`. The fourth argument is the name of the column to get the data from, not the value. As it is, you are not providing any values for any of the parameters, hence the error message telling you that.

Create the parameters properly. Use this overload of `Add` for data types that require a size:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add(sParamName, MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = sDataValue
```

and this overload for those that don't:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add(sParamName, MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = sDataValue
```

Comment: please see the pic